# Surjective linear transformation in $\mathbb R^2$ is injective

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ be a surjective linear transformation. Prove that $T$ is injective without using the rank-nullity theorem

Is there a way to prove this theoremn, without the rank-nullity theorem?; I really don´t see it. Please I would really appreciate if you can give me some hints

Answer (score 1):

This can be done on any finite dimensional space $V$: suppose $T\colon V\to V$ is not injective; then $T$ is not surjective.

Proof. Let $\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ (with $k\ge 1$ because $T$ is not injective) be a basis of the kernel (null space) of $T$. Complete it to a basis of $V$, say
$\{v_1,\dots,v_k,v_{k+1},\dots,v_n\}$.

Then $\{T(v_1),\dots,T(v_k),T(v_{k+1}),\dots,T(v_n)\}$ is a generating set of the image of $T$. Since $T(v_j)=0$ for $1\le j\le k$, also $\{T(v_{k+1}),\dots,T(v_n)\}$ is a set of generators of the image. Hence the image has dimension at most $n-k<n$.

Just for being more concrete, let $V=\mathbb{R}^2$. If $\ker T\ne\{0\}$, choose $v\ne0$, $v\in\ker T$. Take a vector $w$ such that $\{v,w\}$ is linearly independent, hence a basis.

If $u=\alpha v+\beta w\in \mathbb{R}^2$, then $T(u)=\beta T(w)$, so all elements in the image are scalar multiples of $T(w)$ and so the dimension of the image is at most $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Assume that $f(x)=0$ for $x\neq 0$ and $y$ be independent of $x$. What can you say about $f(ax+by)$ (and the image of $f$)?..

Comment: $f(ax+by)=af(x)+bf(y)=bf(y)$ we also have that  {$x,y$} is a basis (they are independent) and as $f$ is surjective for every $z\in \mathbb R^2$ exists $w=ax+by\in \mathbb R^2$ so that $f(w)=z$ but we have that $z=bv$ where $v=f(y)$ so every vector $z$ is a multiple of $v$ which is a contradiction is this correct?

Comment: @user128422 Something like that. If the image is just the span of $f(y)$, it is not surjective, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

First observe that for any non-empty set $S\subseteq \Bbb R^2$, $T(\text{Span}\, (S))=\text{Span}\,(T(S))$. Now since $T$ is surjective, we have $\Bbb R^2=\text{Range}(T)=T(\text{Span (B)})=\text{Span}(T(B))=\text{Span}\{Te_1,Te_2\}$, where $B=\{e_1,e_2\}$ the standard basis for $\Bbb R^2$. Since $\{Te_1,Te_2\}=B_1$ has two elements and generates $\Bbb R^2$, it follows that $B_1$ is a basis for $\Bbb R^2$ and so $B_1$ is linearly independent.

Now choose $x\in \ker T$ and let $x=ae_1+be_2$ be its unique  representation. Then $0=Tx=aTe_1+bTe_2$. Hence $a=0=b$ as $B_1$ is linearly independent. Thus $x=0$ and consequently $\ker T=\{0\}\implies T$ is injective.